# How to Clean a file from annotation? (Maybe a regular expression)

Tags: java, regex

I have a file which contains this text

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements LSLEntity, HasUUID {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "facebook_id", unique=true)
    private String facebookId;

    @UUID
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
    private String uuid;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_info_id")
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="balanced_customer_id")
    @Transient
    private BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Session session;
```

I need to clean up the file from the annotation. I wrote a simple Java program that downloads data from a file

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File( "C:\\test.txt" );
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream( file ), "UTF-8"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println( line );
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Now, I need to clean up the data from the annotation to eventually happened

```
public class User implements LSLEntity, HasUUID {

private Long id;
private String facebookId;
private String uuid;
private UserInfo userInfo;
private BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer;
private Session session;
```

I want to use regular expressions. Please tell me a good article, or example, or it may have another solution to the problem?

Comment: The regex u need is ^@ which means "any line that starts with @"

Comment: @Pavel is `@Entity @Table(name = "User") public class User implements LSLEntity` on a same line?

Comment: yes but there is a problem that there are annotations @Override which should be left

Comment: @PavelPetrashov please format your input.

Comment: @Avinash Raj not on the two lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead based regex like below.

```
Pattern p = Patten.compile("(?m)^(?! *@).+");
```

Negative lookahead `(?! *@)` at the start asserts that there isn't an `@` symbol present at the the start. If yes, then the following one or more characters would be captured.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vP5yA0/1)

```
String input = "@Entity\n" + 
                "@Table(name = \"User\")\n" +
                "public class User implements LSLEntity, HasUUID {\n" +
                "@JoinColumn(name=\"user_info_id\")\n" +
                "    private UserInfo userInfo;";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^(?! *@) *(.+)").matcher(input);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
public class User implements LSLEntity, HasUUID {
private UserInfo userInfo;
```

Comment: you could give a small example?

Comment: but there is a problem that there are annotations @Override which should be left

Comment: did you want to match `@override` ? But you did explain that in your question.

Comment: No, I want to in case the annotation is @override leave it

Comment: my first regex won't match the lines which has `@` at the start. SO it won't match `@Override` also..

Answer (score 1):

why bother java? just run `grep -v ^@ [yourfile.java]` from your command line.

[EDIT]

grep:

> -v means invert-match:
>   Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.

`^` means match start of line. this will match lines start with `@`

BTW, you could also try sed:
`sed '/^@/d' test`

Comment: but you can tell more about it?

Comment: as a whole should happen. I run the program, it clears all classes of annotations, and copies them to a separate folder. I need to leave in the same folder classes with annotations and the second without.

Comment: please run `sed -i '/^@/d' test`. you changed your requirement?

Comment: No, I have bad English (((ie I need to take the file and create a copy of it but without annotations

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

```
\s*@\w+(\s|\(.*\)\s)
```

This would preserve the lines with annotations just before a Java statement i.e. all on the same line like the following possible class declaration:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "User") public class User implements LSLEntity
```

Here I've applied the regex on the file contents by calling `String#replaceAll()` and printed the output to console. You could write this out to a new file if you like. Note that a backslash `\` in a regex expression has to be escaped with `\\` in a Java string.

```
String line;
StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    text.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
br.close();
System.out.println(text.toString().replaceAll("\\s*@\\w+(\\s|\\(.*\\)\\s)", ""));
```

***Output:***

```
public class User implements LSLEntity, HasUUID {
    private Long id;
    private String facebookId;
    private String uuid;
    private UserInfo userInfo;
    private BalancedCustomer balancedCustomer;
    private Session session;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet; the new file will be available in `CleanTest.txt`. Make sure that the line containing annotation doesn't contain anything else than the annotation details.

```
    File file = new File( "C:\\test.txt" );
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream( file ), "UTF-8"));
    File cleanFile = new File("C:\\CleanTest.txt");
    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(cleanFile));
    StringBuilder cleanLines = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    String cleanLine = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        cleanLine = line.replaceAll("^@.*$", "");
        if(cleanLine.trim().length() > 0) {
            cleanLines.append(line.replaceAll("^@.*$", ""));
            cleanLines.append("\n");
        }

    }
    output.write(cleanLines.toString());
    br.close();
    output.close();
```